# mat-select multiple not correctly binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I got a mat select with multiple option

```
      <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label i18n>Languages</mat-label>
    <mat-select
      id="availableLanguages"
      [(ngModel)]="eventGroup!.availableLanguages"
      multiple
    >
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let language of AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES"
        [value]="language.key"
        (onSelectionChange)="updateEventDescriptions()"
        >{{ language.value }}</mat-option
      >
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

I am binding to my event group.availableLanguages
And my options are coming from AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES

AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES looks like the following:

```
export const GERMAN = {
  key: 'de',
  value: 'German',
};

export const ENGLISH = {
  key: 'en',
  value: 'English',
};

export const FRENCH = {
  key: 'fr',
  value: 'French',
};

export const ITALIAN = {
  key: 'it',
  value: 'Italian',
};

export const AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES = [GERMAN, ENGLISH, FRENCH, ITALIAN];
```

I select `["de"]` as default
This will look like the following which is fine

[Multiple Select after Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk3x4.png)

Also if I print eventGroup.availableLanguages it is printing `["de"]` correctly
However if I unselect it it will still print `["de"]`
But then if I select it again it will print `[]`

If I select all languages it will print `["de", "en", "fr"]` with "it" being missing in the list